# Replacing django decorator commit_manually with non_atomic_requests

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a Django view which imports an Excel file, and if exceptions occur I would like to catch them and report them all, and roll back any saves. I'm getting a TransactionManagementError even though I have used the non_atomic_requests decorator.

1. As I'm also using the login_required decorator I thought they might be interfering with each other. First I reversed the order then I removed the login required. No change.
2. I've tried disabling automatic transactions globally. Maybe I didn't do it right but it's not the solution I want anyway.
3. I removed the offending line of code (see below) but the same error occurred when I tried to rollback

It is running on Python 3.7.3 with the latest Django and using SQLlite. I'm running it as a unit test right now, although perhaps I'm abusing the term. Suffice to say it's running as a Django TestCase.

```py
@transaction.non_atomic_requests
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/?next=/finance/gl_upload/')
def gl_upload(request):
    transaction.set_autocommit(False)
    if upriv(request.user, ['admin', 'finance']) == 'admin':
        if request.method == 'POST':

... file processing here ...

                except Exception as e:
                    errs.append(format('Exception "{1}" at row {0}\n'.format(p['rownum'], e)))
                if errs:
                    transaction.rollback()
                    rows_deleted = 0
                    rows_inserted = 0
                    print(''.join('Error: {0}\n'.format(e) for e in errs))
                else:
                    transaction.commit()
                    rows_deleted = Gldata.objects.filter(item='Actual', period_gte=older, period_lte=newest).delete()
                    rows_inserted = Gldata.objects.filter(item=temp_item).update(item='Actual')
                transaction.set_autocommit(True)
                print('Deleted: {0}, inserted: {1}'.format(rows_delete, rows_inserted))
                return render(request, 'gl_upload.html', {'inserted': rows_inserted, 'removed': rows_deleted, 'errors': errs})
            else:
                return render(request, 'gl_upload.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            form = uploadForm()
            return render(request, 'gl_upload.html', {'form': form})
```

I receive a TransactionManagementError on the set_autocommit indicating that an atomic block is active even though I understood that the decorator would disable it. A few years back I used the old commit_manually decorator which worked just fine.

File "C:\Users\csullivan\responsive\finance\views.py", line 25, in gl_upload
    transaction.set_autocommit(False)
  File "C:\Users\csullivan\responsive\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\transaction.py", line 30, in set_autocommit
    return get_connection(using).set_autocommit(autocommit)
  File "C:\Users\csullivan\responsive\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 394, in set_autocommit
    self.validate_no_atomic_block()
  File "C:\Users\csullivan\responsive\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 433, in validate_no_atomic_block
    "This is forbidden when an 'atomic' block is active.")
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: This is forbidden when an 'atomic' block is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the [`atomic()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) 
decorator/context manager provides exactly what you need
--it commits the transaction if the underlying code succeeds and rolls back
when there's an exception.

So in your case I would just do:

```
with atomic():
  process_xls_files()
```

You shouldn't need to call `transaction.set_autocommit()` and similar low-level methods manually,
unless you have very specific needs and the "normal" transaction handling is not enough.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz. Atomic is the default for views isn't it? I want the view to read the entire file and keep track of errors it finds, if any. If there is no error, then I want to commit the INSERT(s), if there are errors, I want to roll back and include the list of errors in the response. I don't want to read the whole file into memory and do one huge bulk_create, which would be the other approach. as this file is 50K rows and another similar exercise will be 120K rows.

Comment: @Deepstop Autocommit is the default unless you use the `ATOMIC_REQUESTS=True` setting. Based on what you say, the `with atomic():` way will do exactly what you need--the DB transaction will "accumulate" all your `INSERT`s and if there's no error they will be commited as soon as the atomic block exits. And if there's an error the whole transaction will be rolled back.

Comment: By the way - even if you set `ATOMIC_REQUESTS=True`, `atomic()` would help as it would then create a savepoint which would work in a similar way (the major difference would be that a commited savepoint can still be rolled back, e.g. when the whole transaction is rolled back).

Comment: It's a little convoluted, but it works. The whole processing loop is in the with block, and at the end of the loop if the errs list is populated I just raise a generic exception and catch it outside the with block. While I have to say I like the explicit commit and rollback better, thank you for pointing me to a working solution!

Comment: @Deepstop I'm glad that it works now! I would say that managing transactions manually is much more tricky, comparing to the "magic" of `atomic()`. The whole point of `atomic()` is that it _always_ does the correct thing and so it's very hard to accidentally introduce a bug. Whereas the manual way is error-prone, as you need to cover each&every possible scenario. Also, multiple nested `atomic()` blocks interact properly, with the outermost handling the transaction and the inner ones handling the savepoint(s).